# regex pattern search for date format MMDDYYYY(python)

Tags: python, string, list, datetime

I have a list of dates, I want to search for MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYYY or YYYYMMDD using regex. I have been using dateutil and regex pattern to find them but I later realized that dateutil doesn't match for this formats. SO I used regex but the regex pattern matches all kind of values(eg:`55122020`)maybe it is counting it has integers. Is there any pattern which can able to match this kind of Date formats?

```
lst = ['2020/12/22','20200322', '34252020']
D = r'^(?:(?:19|20)\d{2}([-/]?)\d{1,2}\1\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}([-/]?)\d{1,2}\2(?:19|20)\d{2})$'
for i in lst:
    if re.search(D, str(i)) != None:
        print(i)
    else:
        print('not matched')

Output:
2020/12/22
20200322
34252020
```

But in actual real world the last value is invalid so the output should be 'not matched' . Is there any pattern which matches this scenario?

```
Actual output:
2020/12/22
20200322
not matched
```

Comment: Try to convert the found value to a date and if it throws an error (that you can catch) the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [dateutil.parser.parse()](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

dates = ['2020/12/22','20200322', '34252020']
for d in dates:
    try:
        d = parse(d)
        print(d)
    except:
        print(d, "isn't a date")
```

---

```
2020-12-22 00:00:00
2020-03-22 00:00:00
34252020 isn't a date
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8cd9c01345)

---

Note:

To parse multiple dates in a `str`, you may also want to use [datefinder](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder):

Comment: Many Thanks, I have one more doubt. It won't match mmddyyyy or ddmmyyyy formats right?

Comment: Please give a try to find out.